# PHP explode function int

Tags: php, arrays

All viewers I need help regarding PHP `explode()` function.

```
$line = 'dd=541;nn=874;cc=21;mm=95;tt=41';
$lineexp = explode(';', $line);
print_r($lineexp);
```

This will produce the following output:

```
[
    0 => 'dd=541',
    1 => 'nn=874',
    2 => 'cc=21',
    3 => 'mm=95',
    4 => 'tt=41'
]
```

**How can I get just the value of the array as array instead?**

Desired output:

```
[
    0 => 541,
    1 => 874,
    2 => 21,
    3 => 95,
    4 => 41
]
```

Comment: Using a `foreach` loop… You could use explode again on the results, with "=" as parameter. Or you could use regex to clean each result. Or you could take a substr() of each result, as the "xx=" variables seem to be always the same lenght…

Comment: You have fallen into the "I have a string, thus I shall use explode" trap. That's oftentimes the worst approach for string extraction.

Comment: Well, filter your array entries by a simple callback function: `$result = array_map(function($item) {
        return filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    }, $data);`.

Answer (score 3):

Just one option to do it. Iterate over array and `substr` after `=` character:

```
$line = 'dd=541;nn=874;cc=21;mm=95;tt=41';
$lineexp = explode(';', $line);

$lineexp = array_map(function($item){
    return substr($item, strpos($item, '=')+1);
}, $lineexp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$line= "dd=541;nn=874;cc=21;mm=95;tt=41"; 
$lineexp = explode(';', $line);

$farray=array();
foreach ($lineexp as $n){
 $nv = explode("=",$n)[1];
array_push($farray,$nv);
 }
var_dump($farray);

?>
```

some thing like this i think 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07a886132e8d0ae1c61f47997faa72d0cc33fd8f

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. your code is working very fine, thanks ones again..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) and use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) using the `=` as the delimiter and return the second part `[1]` which contains the number:

```
$line= "dd=541;nn=874;cc=21;mm=95;tt=41";
$lineexp = array_map("expl", explode(';', $line));

function expl($value) {
    return explode('=', $value)[1];
};
```

Or with inline anonymous function:

```
$lineexp = array_map(function ($a) {
    return explode('=', $a)[1];
}, explode(';', $line));

var_dump($lineexp);
```

That would give you:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "541"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "874"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "21"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "95"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "41"
}
```